# Google Drive API - Override Owner in Shared Folder

Tags: google-drive-api

When sharing a folder, is it possible for the owner to override permissions of the files other writers have created under the folder? Hopefully this can be done with a normal Google account, but requiring Google Apps access is also OK (as long as we only need the owner's, not an admin's credentials to do so)

Comment: If the folder's owner is file's owner too, it is surely possible. If not, then the option **Prevent editors from changing access and adding new people** present in **Sharing settings** must be unchecked. If the option is unchecked, even people with writers and readers access can change file/folder permissions . [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update) to edit permission

Comment: @AbhijeetKumarGaur Does this option allow the folder owner to revoke the file owner's permissions?

Comment: NO. File/Folder ownership can be transferred by owners only. It can't be done by someone else

Comment: @AbhijeetKumarGaur that is what I am asking in the question.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, files inside the shared folders inherits the sharing permissions set by the folder owner. Which means that, permissions set by file owners were overridden by the permissions set by the folder owner as  demonstrated in this [YouTube video - Steegle.com - Google Drive & Docs - Sharing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFFG_S6ahhY&t=4m20s).

However, please note that there are only certain operations which the folder owner can permit and this does not include change of ownership of files as given in [Types, roles and values: how the permissions work](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing#types_roles_and_values_how_the_permissions_work).

This discussion on [Sharing folders vs sharing files - which has priority](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Xe4UN4FMNP4) in Google Docs Help Forum might also help.

Comment: The functionality I need is to prevent people from deleting files they created in the shared folder; guess that's not possible with the current permission model.